# select box append with js variable

Tags: javascript

```
function trig(){        
        var a=$('#rolAdd option:selected').text();
        var b=$('#rolAdd option:selected').attr("value");

     $("#rolRemove").html("<option value='b'> a </option>");

}
```

how can i use a & b variables from rolAdd select box in rolRemove select box...

Comment: `$("#rolRemove").html("<option value='"+b+"'>"+a+"</option>");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
$("#rolRemove").html("<option value='"+b+"'>"+ a + "</option>");
```